# retrieve data by Sqlserver query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table 1 is H and is a Header
Table 2 Is B and Is a Body

this is Table 1 : H

| ACCID | AccName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Acc1 |
| 2 | Acc2 |
| 3 | Acc3 |

this is Table 2 : B

| ID | AccID_receive | AccID_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

I WNANT this Result

| ID | AccID_receive | AccID_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acc1 | Acc2 |
| 2 | Acc1 | Acc2 |
| 3 | Acc2 | Acc3 |

Here what I Have tried

```
Select B.ID,
       H.AccName
From B
left join H
               on B.AccID_receive = H.AccID
```

But the result is Not Ok with me I want the name of Accname in the 2 Column

Comment: Did you try to put, the Accname, in the 2nd column?  (Or why did you repeat `B.ID` in your SELECT statement ?)

Comment: sorry For Repeat B.ID I Updated it now it was mistake

Comment: Please use [edit] and add the result you want, because currently that is not clear.

Comment: ok next time .. thank you ;)

Comment: you just need to left join the account table again on the accid_payment?